# is it possible to use `docker` volumes in development with host user permissions?

Tags: docker, development, rkt

`docker` looks like comfortable tool for sharing development environment.

But sharing host volumes has the important drawback.
`docker` usually (always?) runs container under `root` user, and `docker` creates new files with `root` permissions, that is a problem.

So, how to avoid this problem?

- use custom `Dockerfile`, `entrypoint` for every user and run `docker` with `-u` flag?
- use `rkt`?

Answer (score 0):

Docker is not typically used for this purpose. Rather, it's [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) that's convenient for sharing development environments. In fact, there's a [sub-command expressly for this purpose](https://www.vagrantup.com/intro/getting-started/share.html).